How to handle cedilla(ç) in pyspark?
I am using pyspark 2.4.8 and python 2.7.
I have a file that has cedilla as line separator and ^|^ as record delimiter, how to read this file?
For example:
Fname^|^Snameç
Animesh^|^Ranjanç

I tried reading this file. But getting below error
UnicodeEncodeErorr: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc7' in position 17213: ordinal not in range(128)

This question is similar to: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc7' in position 0: when writting to .csv. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
